# I am using VS code and cout is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cout

I am using VS code on Ubuntu 19.04 and I'm trying to run a very simple program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << "hello";
    //some other simple stuff
```

I am stepping through this code using gdb. My `launch.json` file is as follows:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/project1_debug",
            "args": ["-c queue", "-f stack"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The other "simple stuff" below cout works fine, it's just that `cout` is not working. I checked the Output, Problems and Debug Console and none of them show any output.

Here's what my debug console says:

```
Loaded '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2'. Symbols loaded.

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdeb8) at project1.cpp:6
6   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6'. Symbols loaded.

Breakpoint 2, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdeb8) at project1.cpp:8
8       cout << "hello";
Execute debugger commands using "-exec <command>", for example "-exec info registers" will list registers in use (when GDB is the debugger)
Kill the program being debugged? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

I don't understand why cout isn't working.

Comment: Probably isn't the problem but try flushing the buffer.

Comment: What happens if you run the program from a terminal window, rather than going through your IDE (VS Code)?

Comment: @JaMiT it worked! But is there a way to make it work so that the output is shown as I step through the code? Because in other programs like Visual studio that's what happens and it's a very convenient feature

Comment: @user10796158 Sorry, I don't know Visual Studio Code well enough to answer that. However, you did confirm the appropriateness of adding a tag for the IDE. All I can say is that the "externalConsole" line looks suspicious to me.

Comment: If you want the data to be visible now, you better flush it. `cout << "hello";` doesn't flush, so "hello" may hang around in the buffer until the program exits and the stream is forced to flush in the destructor before closing.

Comment: @user4581301 how do you do that?

Comment: Documentation for [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) Side note: flush can be expensive, so only do it when you need to do it. A flush is also implied in `std::endl`, so if all you need to do is add a line feed to a stream, prefer to send a newline character(`'\n'`).

Comment: @user4581301 so I tried endl, it didn't help. But I tried something else that someone suggested: setting externalConsole in launch.json to true. I now basically get an external console with the output that I want

Comment: @user10796158 I'll log that in the win column.

Answer (score 1):

The output is in the TERMINAL tab, select the "number: cppdbg: filename" tag from the drop-down menu

Answer (score 0):

I just set `externalConsole` to true in my `launch.json` and I now get the output that I want in an external console (i.e new bash)

Comment: The external console  likely exits when the program does, so if you want to see the output at the end of the program you may have to add another option in the config file (Not a VSC user so my knowledge here is limited) or place a breakpoint at the end of the program tto force a halt for inspection.